# Why is this code using all the cores in my computer?

Tags: python, numpy, parallel-processing

I was trying to parallelize the following code and my surprise was big, to say the least, when I found that that running this code actually uses all the cores of my computer (numpy 1.15.1, Ubuntu 18.04, 24 cores)!!!

```
import numpy as np

if __name__ == '__main__':
    q = np.random.rand(200,3)
    bi = np.random.rand(2000)
    tr = np.random.rand(1000, 2000, 3)

    def serial_worker(frame):
        exponents = np.tensordot(frame, q, axes=(1, 1))
        exponentials = np.exp(1j * exponents)
        return np.tensordot(bi, exponentials, axes=1)

    amps = np.asarray([serial_worker(frame) for frame in tr])
```

[image]

Both `python2 script.py` and `python3 script.py` use all cores. Is numpy preconfigured to used all cores? Otherwise, can anybody please explain to me how can determine which lines are being executed in parallel?

Comment: Yes, `numpy` / `scipy` calls BLAS/LAPACK routines under the hood, and can very well be parallelized already.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga  Then the same code would use only one core if the BLAS/LAPACK routines were compiled in serial mode, right?